# How do I manually configure NI Visa on linux

Tags: visa

I'm trying to get the National Instruments Visa library (without Labview) working on a Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.7 PC. It comes with some configuration utilities (NIvisaic & visaconf) to find and setup the instruments but after a week of trying we've given up trying to get them to run. I know from windows it's just a configuration text file visaconf.ini but I don't know where to put it or if it's the same file  & format for linux. Bottom line, how do I manually configure NI Visa in Linux ?

Comment: On Windows you rarely need to "configure" anything other than RS-232 and only then if you want different setting than the Windows device manger. Perhaps Linux is similar.

Comment: Nope. Every instruments alias has to be set up. They're using 'driver' loosely. The Visa library is more of a bridge (if that's the right term.) Windows device manager has nothing to do with it. The instruments themselves are on the Ethernet bus. I can ping them so I know the PC can see them. BTW, I tried copying the visaconf.ini file over & sprinkling it around every visa related directory I could find. No luck. I don't know if it's the filename or location or format. I'm using the pyvisa python module to test the installation. The resource manager in pyvisa still only sees the local host.

Comment: Resource managers are not required to return anything other than at least an empty list. Aliases are not required because a full resource string would work without a configuration. Obviously both are handy and can add significantly to an application...sorry I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the PyVISA library?

https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: PyVisa is exactly what I want to use. But apparently I have to configure the instruments to use it first. Right now the ResourceManager.list()_resources just lists the local host. The instruments are on the ethernet. Is there a way to discover them & talk to them with pyvisa without configuring them first for visa?

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue. Are they discoverable on the LAN via nmap?

Comment: No. I can ping the instruments. And I can talk to them with pyvisa from a windows box on the same network.

Comment: So you don't see the when running `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0-255`? Replace the first three blocks  with your LAN /24.